# Can information security risks essentially only be triaged according to the CIA triangle?

Tags: risk-management, risk-analysis, risk, risk-classification

Can information security risks essentially only be triaged according to the CIA triangle (Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability) or are there other possibilities?

[image: CIA triangle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There are lots of other possibilities.**

Note that the CIA triad is not so much a model for security risks as it is for security goals/objectives. It has often been [criticized](https://telicthoughts.blogspot.de/2009/02/when-one-thinks-of-securing-information.html) for being overly simplistic and incomplete. Consequently, there are lots of alternative models and extensions of the CIA triad. One popular option is the [Parkerian hexad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkerian_Hexad) that consists of *confidentiality*, *possession*, *integrity*, *authenticity*, *availability* and *utility*. Others [have suggested](https://securopia.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/security-models-cia-and-ciaan/) extending it with *authenticity* and *non-repudiation* to the CIAAN model.

---

If your primary goal is threat risk modeling, there are other models to consider - which can still be associated with the CIA triad. For example, there is the [STRIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STRIDE_(security)) model which classifies threats via the categories *spoofing*, *tampering*, *repudiation*, *information disclosure*, *denial of service* and *elevation of privilege*. Here is how it relates to CIA:

> STRIDE is what an attacker can do. TID is the attack version of CIA:
>
> - Defenders want Confidentiality – attackers use Information Disclosure
> - Defenders want Integrity – attackers use Tampering
> - Defenders want Availability – attackers use Denial of Service.
>
> But, what about Spoofing, Repudiation and Elevation of Privilege? Enter the (modern) non-linear attack:
>
> - Spoofing and Elevation of Privilege are the entry points to pry open the doors.
> - Repudiation is covering the adversary’s tracks during the initial compromise and the breach.

[(Source)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heinrichg/2016/06/07/stride-cia-and-the-modern-adversary/)